# Mouse interaction don't work with react bootstrap button;

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

-When in desktop and laptop mode (without sidebar in parent component) mouse interaction with react bootstrap button is working, when I  change and add sidebar (from react-sidebar library) the mouse pointer doesn't event recognize it is a button anymore. The calling of functions are not problem, because it work's when react-sidebar is not here. This only happends with MyProfile component.

-Is there some way to force mouse pointer to recognize the button as the button?

-I tried using z-index but it doesn't work. Here is my code of MyProfile component:

```js
            <div key={this.props.loggedInUser.uid.toString()} >
                <Well className="profileHeader"> <h1 className="headerOfMyProfile">  <span role="img" aria-label="icon"></span> {this.props.loggedInUser.displayedName} </h1> </Well>
                {this.state.urlOfImage !== ''?
                <img alt="profileImage" className="profileImage" src={this.state.urlOfImage}  /> : <img alt="profileImage" className="profileImage" src={require("./images/UserImage.png")} />} 
                <OverlayTrigger placement="bottom" overlay={tooltipForEditableImageOfUser}> 
                    <Button key='editImageOfUser' onClick={this.showDialogForEditOfImageOfUser}  className="buttonForEditableImageOfUser"> <Twemoji text="️" /> </Button>
                </OverlayTrigger> 
                <br /> <br /> 
                <Table className={'tableToPutCeratinUserInfo'}>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <i> E-mail: </i> </td>
                        <td> <b> {this.props.loggedInUser.email} </b> </td>
                    </tr>
                </Table>
                <br/> <br/>
                <OverlayTrigger placement="bottom" overlay={tooltipForProfileInformation}>
                    <Button key='editProfileInformation' placeholder="Izmenite profilne informacije" onClick={this.showModalForUpdateOfData} className="changeProfileInformation"> <span role="img" aria-label="icon">✏️</span> </Button>
                </OverlayTrigger>
                <OverlayTrigger placement="bottom" overlay={tooltipForPasswordInformation}>
                    <Button key='changePassword' placeholder="Izmenite lozinku" onClick={this.showModalForInsertionOfPasswordAgain} className="changePassword"><span role="img" aria-label="icon"></span></Button>
                </OverlayTrigger>
                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.showModalForUpdateOfData} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="ℹ️" />  Modifikovanje vaših podataka <Button onClick={this.cancelUpdateOfData} className="hideUpdateOfData"> <Twemoji  text="❌" />   </Button>  </h3>
                        <div className="messageForWarning"> <i className="warningMessageBeforeAddingANewAd"> <Twemoji text="⚠️" />Upozorenje: nakon promene podataka, morate se vratiti ponovo na karticu "Moj profil". </i> </div> <br/>
                        <Well> 
                            <Form noValidate={true} horizontal={false}>
                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Row sm={2}>
                                        <h3> Unesite novi email: </h3>
                                        <InputGroup>
                                            <FormControl required inputRef={inputNewEmail => this.inputNewEmail = inputNewEmail} type="text" defaultValue={loggedInUser.email} />
                                        </InputGroup>
                                        <Button onClick={this.updateUserData}>Podnesi</Button>
                                    </Row>
                                </FormGroup>
                            </Form>  
                        </Well>
                </Modal>
                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.showModalForInsertionOfPasswordAgain} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="ℹ️" />  Resetovanje lozinke <Button onClick={this.cancelTheResetOfPassword} className="hideResetPasswordModal"> <Twemoji  text="❌" />   </Button>  </h3> <br/>
                        <Well> 
                            <Form noValidate={true} horizontal={false}>
                                <FormGroup>
                                    <Row sm={2}>
                                        <h3> Unesite novu lozinku: </h3>
                                        <InputGroup>
                                            <FormControl required inputRef={inputNewPassword => this.inputNewPassword = inputNewPassword} type="password" placeholder="Nova lozinka" />
                                            <FormControl required inputRef={inputNewPasswordRepeat => this.inputNewPasswordRepeat = inputNewPasswordRepeat} type="password" placeholder="Ponovite novu lozinku" />
                                        </InputGroup>
                                        <Button onClick={this.resetThePassword}>Podnesi</Button>
                                    </Row>
                                </FormGroup>
                            </Form>  
                        </Well>
                </Modal>

                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.notificationOfSuccessfulUpdateOfPassword} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="ℹ️" />  Uspešno resetovana lozinka! </h3>
                        <Well> 
                            Uspešno ste resetovali lozinku! 
                        </Well>
                        <Button onClick={this.hideNotificationOfSuccessfulUpdateOfPassword}>Ok</Button>
                </Modal>

                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.notificationOfToShortNewPassword} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="⚠️" />  Prekratka lozinka! </h3>
                        <Well> 
                            Lozinka mora da ima najmanje 6 karaktera! 
                        </Well>
                        <Button onClick={this.hideNotificationOfToShortNewPassword}>Ok</Button>
                </Modal>

                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.notificationOfToShortNewPassword} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="⚠️" />  Prekratka lozinka! </h3>
                        <Well> 
                            Lozinka mora da ima najmanje 6 karaktera! 
                        </Well>
                        <Button onClick={this.hideNotificationOfToShortNewPassword}>Ok</Button>
                </Modal>
                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.notificationOfEmptyFields} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="⚠️" />  Polja ne smeju biti prazna! </h3>
                        <Well> 
                            Morate popuniti sva polja!
                        </Well>
                        <Button onClick={this.hideNotificationOfEmptyFields}>Ok</Button>
                </Modal>
                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.showNotificationOfWrongInsertedEmail} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="⚠️" />  E-mail nije unet u validnom svetu! </h3>
                        <Well> 
                            E-mail morate uneti u ispravnom formatu!
                        </Well>
                        <Button onClick={this.hideNotificationOfWrongInsertedEmail}>Ok</Button>
                </Modal>
                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.showAlertThatPasswordAreNotTheSame} >
                        <h3> <Twemoji text="⚠️" />  Lozinke moraju biti iste! </h3>
                        <Well> 
                            Dve unete lozinke se moraju poklapati
                        </Well>
                        <Button onClick={this.hideAlertThatPasswordAreNotTheSame}>Ok</Button>
                </Modal>
                <Modal className="myProfileModal"  show={this.state.showDialogForEditOfImageOfUser}>
                    <h3> <Twemoji text="️" />  Izmenite profilnu sliku <Button onClick={this.hideDialogForEditOfImageOfUser} className="hideModalForEditAd"> <Twemoji  text="❌" />   </Button> <br/></h3> 
                    <div className="messageForWarning"> <i className="warningMessageBeforeAddingANewAd"> <Twemoji text="⚠️" />Upozorenje: ako ne želite promeniti sliku, morate uneti neku. Nakon unosa, morate se vratiti na karticu "Moj profil". </i> </div> <br/>
                    <Well>
                        <Form className="formGroupCreateAd" noValidate={false} horizontal>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Col sm={2}>
                                    Unesite novu sliku:
                                </Col>
                                <Col sm={5}>
                                    <InputGroup>
                                        <FormControl required accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .svg, .png"  inputRef={inputUserImage => this.inputUserImage = inputUserImage} type="file" placeholder="Nova slika" />
                                    </InputGroup>
                                </Col>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup className="buttonsForCreateAd">
                                <Row>
                                    <Button className="confirmationOfAdANewAd" onClick={this.updateProfileImageOfUser}> Zapamti </Button>
                                    <Button onClick={this.hideDialogForEditOfImageOfUser}> Otkaži </Button>
                                </Row> 
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>   
                     </Well>
                </Modal>
            </div>
```

Comment: This is rather a lot of code to look through, are you able to provide a smaller, working example? I think you'd be more likely to get some good responses if there was a little less code here.

Comment: I have only extracted the render part of the code so you could have easily time seeing it...

Comment: I have answered the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53377779/9427976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add position:relative, css to the div which holds everything, because when the sidebar is added, the content is moved to the left, from it's normal position, so it is probably expecting handler over there.